# Tensorflow: Get correct accuracy of NN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm stuck too long and would need some help (very new to tensorflow etc). I modified an MNIST example to my own data but keep getting 100% accuracy, even after 2 epochs.
My X is (similar to MNIST) a [18, 1]-vector and y a float32.
**variables:**

```
n_nodes_hl1 = 100
n_nodes_hl2 = 100
n_nodes_hl3 = 50
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 18], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1],  dtype=tf.float32)
x_vals_train = np.array([])
y_vals_train = np.array([])
x_vals_test = np.array([])
y_vals_test = np.array([])
loss_vec = []
```

**my model:**

```
def neural_net_model(data):
  hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([18,n_nodes_hl1])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
  hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1,n_nodes_hl2])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
  hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2,n_nodes_hl3])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

  output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3,1])),
    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))}

  l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']),hidden_1_layer['biases'])
  l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
  l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']),hidden_2_layer['biases'])
  l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
  l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']),hidden_3_layer['biases'])
  l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

  output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

  return output
```

**Session:**

```
def train_neural_network(x):
  prediction = neural_net_model(x)
  cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y - prediction))
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      for i in range(10):
          temp_loss = 0

          rand_index = np.random.choice(len(x_vals_train), 50)
          rand_x = x_vals_train[rand_index]
          rand_y = np.transpose([y_vals_train[rand_index]])
          _, temp_loss = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: rand_x, y: rand_y})

          if (i+1)%100==0:
            print('Generation: ' + str(i+1) + '. Loss = ' + str(temp_loss))

      # evaluate accuracy
      correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
      print "accuracy %.5f'" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: x_vals_test, y: np.transpose([y_vals_test])})
```

The question is primarely why I always get 100% accuracy, which is obviously false. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MNIST usually has one-hot coded output. In that case `correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))` makes sense as `tf.argmax` converts the one-hot code to the actual class which is then compared by `tf.equal`.

But in your case since the output dimension is `1` `tf.argmax` outputs `0` which is the only valid index for both and hence they are equal and hence 100% accuracy.

You need to redefine the accuracy appropriate to your case. Assuming the output is a binary value (as accuracy as a metrics only makes sense for binary case) you can use the following:

```
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(prediction), y)
```

Here you are rounding off the `prediction` and then comparing to `y`. For this to work you need to have sigmoid as the final layer activation `output = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)` or you need to clip the predictions:

```
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(tf.clip_by_value(prediction,0,1)), y)
```

Other option for you will be to convert `y_vals_train`, `y_vals_test` to one-hot code and have the network output 2 dimension.

Comment: Now everything looks a little clearer :) thanks. My output is a float (execution time of a query) - so if you have any tips I'm all ears. But you clearly answered the original question.. so I accept

Comment: Well mean squared error is the best metric for real valued output. You can also use mean absolute error as you have in the loss.